# How to fill a form with data from Mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two HTML forms in a php file(Control.php). I have four dropdown list as filters in Form1. once i click submit button in Form1, i have to pass the values selected from Form1 to another php file(Actions.php) through POST method, where i pass query with the filters and retrieve data from Mysql database(if record is present in the database for those filters). I was able to make it work so far.

Now i want to fill my Form2, with the data retrieved from database based on the filters. if no data is available, i want to set all the elements in the form blank for adding new data.

How to add a new data and modify(update) existing data in same Form.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="foo" value="<?php echo $value_from_db ?>" />`

Comment: @MarcB: i know this works. my doubt was that, if the no record is present in database for the filter conditions, whether the same text box can be used to get new data from user??

Comment: it's just a text box. how the data from it is handled is up to you and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data retrieved from the first query to the other pages in the PHP session.  Then your script can simply copy the contents of the session (or NULL) into the value= attributes of the form.